# find smallest index to fit multiple condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group my values together so that the max sum of 2 values comes to a certain value ( here 6 ).

For example, I want to put together (1+5), (3+3), (4+1) and the rest by themselves. For this, I need to be able to search for a certain condition combination, and also ignore it if there is no such number. In the "Grouped" column I keep track of if they have already been grouped, if so then leave them, an index can only be grouped once.

I have:

```
df_1= pd.DataFrame({'Rest_after_division': [1,3,3,4,5,5,1],
                   'Grouped_with_index': ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],
                   'Grouped': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

       Rest_after_division    Grouped_with_index  Grouped
0                 1                  -               0
1                 2                  -               0
2                 3                  -               0
3                 4                  -               0
4                 5                  -               0
5                 5                  -               0
6                 5                  -               0
```

I want:

```
       Rest_after_division    Grouped_with_index  Grouped
0                    1                  4            1
1                    2                  3            1
2                    3                  -            0
3                    4                  1            1
4                    5                  0            1
5                    5                  -            0
6                    5                  -            0
```

I have example 2:

```
df_1= pd.DataFrame({'Rest_after_division': [1,1,1,4,5,5,5],
                   'Grouped_with_index': ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],
                   'Grouped': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

 
         Rest_after_division Grouped_with_index  Grouped
0                    1                  -           0
1                    1                  -           0
2                    1                  -           0
3                    4                  -           0
4                    5                  -           0
5                    5                  -           0
6                    5                  -           0
```

I want example 2:

```
         Rest_after_division Grouped_with_index  Grouped
0                    1                  4           1
1                    1                  5           1
2                    1                  6           1
3                    4                  -           0
4                    5                  0           1
5                    5                  1           1
6                    5                  2           1
```

I have tried: ( i know I need to loop this eventually, but I can't get the index..)

```
df_1 = df_1.sort_values('Grouped')
index_group_buddy= df_1[df_1['Rest_after_division']==5].head(1).index[0]
print(index_group_buddy)
```

This almost works, but not when the condition does not exist, how do I skip this? And I also think it will be problematic when all are grouped...

I have also tried:

```
#index_group_buddy = df_1.loc[((df_1['Rest_after_division'] == 5) & (df_1['Grouped'] != 1)) ].idxmin(axis=1)
#index_group_buddy =df_1.query("Rest_after_division==5 and Grouped!=1")
index_group_buddy = df_1[(df_1['Rest_after_division']==5) & (df_1['Grouped']!=1)].index[0]
df_1.at[index_group_buddy, 'Grouped'] = 1
df_1.at[index_group_buddy, 'Grouped_with_index  '] = index_group_buddy
print(index_group_buddy)
```

I want to find the first index that has the right conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. rework you df_1 to map unique "Rest_after_division" to their index
2. Map the complement to 6 on those keys
3. calculate which values should be grouped (not complement with self and first value of group)
4. insert the values with mask

```
keys = (df_1['Rest_after_division']
            .drop_duplicates()
            .reset_index()
            .set_index('Rest_after_division')
            ['index']
       )

compl_index = (6-df_1['Rest_after_division']).map(keys)

df_1['Grouped'] = (compl_index.ne(df_1.index)
                   & df_1.groupby('Rest_after_division').cumcount().eq(0)
                  ).astype(int)

df_1['Grouped_with_index'] = compl_index.where(df_1['Grouped'].eq(1),
                                               df_1['Grouped_with_index'])
```

output:

```
   Rest_after_division Grouped_with_index  Grouped
0                    1                  4        1
1                    2                  3        1
2                    3                  -        0
3                    4                  1        1
4                    5                  0        1
5                    5                  -        0
6                    1                  -        0
```

Comment: Hi Moyway. Thank you for your fast response.  I see that I have made a mistake in my description. I need all rows if possible to get a grouped_with_index.